# Integer.parseInt() - Signed and Unsigned Number

Tags: java

From [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), I understand that Java, by default, has int data type as a 32-bit signed two's complement integer, which has a minimum value of -2^31 and a maximum value of 2^31-1.

If that is the case, why does this:

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("1111", 2));
```

give a value of 15 instead of -1(2's complement signed number).

Comment: You told it to parse it as a binary number. 1111 is 15 in decimal notation

Comment: It's unclear why you expect this to produce -1 as output

Comment: Maybe you meant `System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("11111111111111111111111111111111", 2));`

Answer (score 5):

You've made an assumption that, because integers are represented internally using two's complement, `Integer.parseInt` with a radix of 2 (binary) also takes numbers in that form. That assumption was incorrect.

Your best bet with stuff like this is to [read the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-int-). There's no mention of two's complement. It does however say:

> the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to
>   indicate a negative value

So if you want to parse values represented using two's complement, you will have to write a function which converts the binary number to the absolute value, then appends a minus if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

According to the javadoc of java.lang.Integer class parseInt(String s, int radix) method does the following;

> Parses the string argument as a signed integer in the radix specified
>   by the second argument. The characters in the string must all be
>   digits of the specified radix.

When you run;

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("1111", 2));
```

You are telling the method to take "1111" as a string and convert it to an int value with a base of 2(your radix), eventually it sums to 15 in binary.

Answer (score 0):

Your input "1111" is actually a shortcut to this string "0000 0000 0000 1111", which represent 15.

For the method `Integer.parseInt(binaryString, 2)`, if your binaryString's first char is not `'-'`, then it means parse an unsigned int.